# 'setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil' exception, how to tell which one

Tags: xcode, debugging

My app is randomly (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't) crashing:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010988ec65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b63bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109793af8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 968
    3   MultipeerConnectivity               0x00000001096e32e2 -[MCNearbyServiceBrowser netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:] + 251
    4   CFNetwork                           0x000000010c2ca2dd -[NSNetServiceBrowser _dispatchCallBack:flags:error:] + 968
    5   CFNetwork                           0x000000010c217fe2 _ZL14_BrowserCancelP21__CFNetServiceBrowser + 133
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097c2431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097b82fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097b7934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001097b7366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d1a3a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a36f8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    12  MyApp                               0x0000000109099137 main + 135
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cccc145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How can I tell in Xcode which line of code, or collection object is causing the problem?

**Update**

I did as the answer and comments suggested, and added the breakpoint with the command, and now, before the error, I get this:

> *** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil
>
> 4354859399
>
> 3534170
>
> 140567501647968
>
> 140567492355160
>
> 140567492355168
>
> 4354751672
>
> 4294967279

I still don't know what that means...

Comment: Have you run your app in the debugger? It will show you the code, call stack, etc.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it (I'm just learning), but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @coopersita, I know I'm asking a few years later. But did you find what the problem was ?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed sorry, but I don’t even remember posting this. I was just starting, so it was likely an outlet not linked properly or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

In your Xcode's left panel, go to the Breakpoints tab, click the `+` button and add an `Exception Breakpoint`. It will catch any exception and tell you where they occur.

[image]

Comment: To add to this: edit your breakpoint exception (right click → Edit Breakpoint), click Add Action, choose Debugger Command from the popup, and type in `po $arg1`. It will print out the exception's `.reason` property every time it is hit.

Comment: Thanks @ZevEisenberg ! Good idea ! Will use that too from now on :)

Comment: This can also be helpful when you hit the problem that OP is asking about. When you hit it, jump back up the stack to the `setObjectForKey:` method, and try `po $arg0`, `po $arg1`, `po $arg2`, etc., until you find the one you need. These are the arguments passed to `objc_msgSend()`.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, and  @ZevEisenberg, please see my update. I added the breakpoint, and the actions, but I only get a bunch of numbers.

Comment: You may also want to cast those `$arg1` values in the debugger on the off chance that they're C strings: `p (char *)$arg1`